# Why is it not possible to embed \if construction in docstrip

Tags: conditionals, dtx, docstrip

I would like to create a DTX files which could be compiled in two different ways depending of a user's choice. One way to get only the user documentation, and another to get user documentation **and** code documentation.

I do not want to use `\StopEventually` since in the second case I do not want to have theses documentations separated in two differents parts, but mixed all along the documentation.

In order to that I setup a DTX template different and simpler than those generally used, *i.e.* the one from [TeX Hacks](http://texhacks.blogspot.fr/2011/01/simpler-dtx-template.html) or from [Joseph Wright](http://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/).

Everything works fine in almost all cases but not in one case I isolated and reduced to this chunk of LaTeX code:

```
% \newif\ifcode
% \codefalse ^^A Change to \codetrue to include code documentation

% \iffalse
%<*documentation>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
 \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</documentation>
%<*latex>
% \fi

% some user command explanations
% \ifcode
% some code explanations
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newif\ifcadre
\cadretrue
\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{
  \ifcadre
    \framebox{title}
  \else
    {title}
  \fi
}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \fi
% some other text
% \iffalse
%</latex>
% \fi
\endinput
```

When I try to compile that with `pdflatex` I get the following error

```
! Too many }'s.
l.27 }

?
```

When line 2 is changed from `\codefalse` to `\codetrue` everything works fine.

When `\ifcadre`, `\else` and `\fi` lines are removed, everything works fine in both cases (with `\codetrue` or `\codefalse` in line 2).

Did I miss something in docstrip documentation ?

Comment: David's given an answer as to _why_: have you considered using `l3doc` for example as an alternative approach?

Comment: No since I did not know about `l3doc`, thank's for the link.
I am not familiar enough with LaTeX 3 conventions and I need something stable (which `l3doc` is not, as warned in the `l3doc.dtx` file itself).
I however really like the `\EnableImplementation`, `\DisableImplementation` approach, since that was what I wanted to do at first. After a first quick read it seems they also use the `comment` environment from the `verbatim` package but in a clever way than I finally did.
I definitively need to take time to read about LaTeX 3 through `texdoc expl3` before going further.

Answer (score 8):

This is not really related to dtx but rather the usual "don't define conditionals in a conditional block" issue:

```
% \ifcode
% some code explanations
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newif\ifcadre
\cadretrue
\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{
  \ifcadre
    \framebox{title}
  \else
```

if `\ifcode` is false then `\begin{macrocode}` is *not* executed  so the block is not read verbatim but skipped while matching if else fi tokens.

`\newif\ifcadre` is not executed so `\ifcadre` is not an `if` but `\else` is an `else` and things go wrong.

Comment: I prefer to use the etoolbox package: ```\newbool{bool@var}``` then set the value with ```\booltrue{bool@var}``` or ```\boolfalse{bool@var}```.
To evaluate them: ```\ifbool{bool@var}{true}{false}```.

Answer (score 3):

[David](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)'s answer is enlightning.

With that explanation a workaround is very easy to set up. Using the `verbatim` package (and its very nicely coded `comment` environment) it is easy to define a `code` environment differently when `\ifcode` is `true` or `false`.

When it's `true` it does nothing (or almost) when it's `false` it *skips* every lines inside it.

Here is the code:

```
% \newif\ifcode
% \codefalse ^^A Change to \codetrue to include code documentation

% \iffalse
%<*documentation>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</documentation>
%<*latex>
% \fi

% \ifcode\let\code\begingroup\let\endcode\endgroup
% \else\let\code\comment\let\endcode\endcomment\fi

% some text explaining things

% \begin{code}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newif\ifcadre
\cadretrue
\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{
  \ifcadre
    \framebox{title}
  \else
    {title}
  \fi
}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{code}

% some other text

% \iffalse
%</latex>
% \fi
\endinput
```

Comment: +1 I was thinking I ought to add working code rather than just say what was wrong, but ran out of time, thanks for picking this up.